# how to add a xml document to another xml document in java

Tags: java, xml, xmldocument

I have a xml document like this rootXMLDoc=`<root> <param></param></root>` . I need to insert paramxmlDoc= `<parameter par='1'>abc</parameter>`. how to insert paramxmlDoc to rootXMLDoc in java.? and i need output like this
`<root>
<parameter par='1'>abc</parameter> 
<param></param>
</root>`

Comment: Which Java XML parser/generator library do you use?  There are many such libraries, so the answer depends on the library that you use.  For example do you use a DOM or SAX XML library?

Comment: Shouldn't you consider deleting this question since you asked a slight variation of the same question shortly after?  (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042592/how-to-insert-a-xml-node-as-first-child-in-another-xml-document-in-java.)

Comment: But the answers for both of my similar questions are different. So I didnt consider to delete this one. May be it ll be useful for someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Element e = paramxmlDoc.getRootElement();
paramxmlDoc.setRootElement(null); // break connection between doc and element
rootXMLDoc.getRootElement().addChild(e); // Insert node in other document
```

Note: This is from memory, so the actual method calls can be slightly different but you get the idea.