# How to add nodes from another xml using xmlbeans

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I am using xmlbeans to generate the xml document, while I need to extract all the children  from another xml file and insert them to my current document.
The `to_be_add.xml`:

```
<root>
    <style>
        .....
    </style>
    <atlas img="styles/jmap.png">
        ....
    </atlas>
    .....
</root>
```

And this xml file does not have a schema so I do not create related java class to map it. You think it as a plain xml file.

I want the `style` `atlas` node added. I use the following codes:

```
        XmlObject pointRoot = XmlObject.Factory.parse(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("to_be_added.xml"));
        NodeList nodeList = pointRoot.getDomNode().getChildNodes();

        Node themeNode = renderthemeDoc.getDomNode();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            themeNode.appendChild(node);
        }
```

Then I got error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.DomImpl$WrongDocumentErr: Child to add
>   is from another document

And I found this post by searching "child to .... another document": [how to add a xml document to another xml document in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035953/how-to-add-a-xml-document-to-another-xml-document-in-java) which said that the connection between the element and the document has to be broken between the element can be add to other document.

So I try to build the `Document` object(that is why the variable `pointDoc` and `themeDoc` exist):

```
        XmlObject pointRoot = XmlObject.Factory.parse(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("to_be_added.xml"));
        Document pointDoc = pointRoot.getDomNode().getOwnerDocument();
        System.out.println(pointDoc);
        Element element = pointDoc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nodeList = element.getChildNodes();

        Document themeDoc = myCurrentDoc.getDomNode().getOwnerDocument();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            node = themeDoc.importNode(node, true);
            themeDoc.appendChild(node);
        }
```

Then I got `NullPointerException` which said that the `pointDoc` is null.

That is the whole process how I try to solve this problem. If it is unclear, please tell me, I will update accordingly.

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe your problem *in detail*, including a larger portion of your XML documents and Java files (including your XML beans classes).

Comment: got this working under XML Beans 2.4.0 using `Document themeDoc = (Document) myCurrentDoc.getDomNode();`

Answer (score -2):

Since your *other* XML file is not mapped to a class, you can use a regular DOM parser to read it and extract its nodes. But using a generic object factory you can still get the nodes:

```
    XmlObject pointRoot = XmlObject.Factory.parse(  "<root>\n" +
                                                    "    <style>\n" +
                                                    "    </style>\n" +
                                                    "    <atlas img=\"styles/jmap.png\">\n" +
                                                    "    </atlas>\n" +
                                                    "</root>");

    Node pointDoc = pointRoot.getDomNode().getFirstChild();
    NodeList nodeList = pointDoc.getChildNodes();

    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Node: " + nodeList.item(i).getNodeName());
    }
```

This will print:

```
Node: #text
Node: style
Node: #text
Node: atlas
Node: #text
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but I am afraid you misunderstand me. I can read the nodes from another xml, but I  have no idea to add them to my current document.

Comment: You said you couldn't: *"However the pointDoc is null. Is it possible to **fix it**?"* What do you mean by that then? If the node is null you couldn't extract the child nodes, that's what I understood. The code above shows how to **fix** that.

Comment: Why I want to get the `Document` object is that I try to break the nodes and the document of the "to_be_added.xml", since the nodes can not added if they are still have connection with another document. Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035953/how-to-add-a-xml-document-to-another-xml-document-in-java